# Custom API in Azure

Tags: javascript, .net, azure, azure-api-management

I have a table of temperatures and dates in Azure. I have a client Windows 8 App. I was wondering how do I pass a date argument from the app into a custom API in Azure.

For example, if the user has selected the 4th July in the app - the date is passed into a custom API in Azure, pulling out the temperatures for that date.

Comment: Azure is a platform, it can be accessed from many different methods in multiple different languages.  Which language is your API implemented in?

Comment: This isn't a question about azure, it's a general question about web/service development. Please provide additional context about the technologies your service is using.

Comment: I've a client app in c#, and I need to use the date selected as an argument in an sql query. The sql query is executed through the custom API, which in Azure, can be written in JavaScript or .net

Comment: @RaymondDillon, please supply some code of what you have tried so far in .net or JavaScript ?